# Create a log file only during error

Tags: c

I am loging error messages using

```
#define LOG_INFO(...) do{ fprintf(fpLogFile, __VA_ARGS__ ); } while( FALSE )
#else
#define LOG_INFO(...) do{ } while ( FALSE )
```

and the `fpLogFile` is opened using `fopen`.
`fopen` creates `0KB` file even if there are no errors.

If a `0KB` file is created, a job is triggered. Hence I want to create the log only if there are errors.

How can I acheive this using `fopen` are there any other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `fpLogFile` to `NULL`, and before each `fprintf`, check if it is still `NULL`. If so, open the file.

Answer (score 1):

I could create a file for each error log

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int g_Error_Num = 0;

#define LOG_INFO(...) \
do{\
    FILE *fpLogFile;\
    char file_name[32];\
    sprintf(file_name, "./Error_LOG_%d.txt", g_Error_Num++);\
    fpLogFile = fopen (file_name, "w+");\
    if (fpLogFile != NULL) {\
        fprintf(fpLogFile, __VA_ARGS__ ); \
        fclose(fpLogFile);\
    }\
} while( 0 )

int main(void)
{
    LOG_INFO("Test 1\n");
    LOG_INFO("Test 2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't scale well. Especially if the macro is used in a hot code section.

Comment: @StoryTeller obviously: do not put it into ISR ;) BTW it is a suggestion, I don't know if applicable Anyway the code can be isolate into a "slow" process that triggers errors to log when is possible to store them.